# Защита ссылок на изображения c#

Tags: c#, безопасность, ссылки, img, webapi

У меня есть Backend(Web API) и Frontend(React), возникла проблема, на сервере в папке лежат изображения я передаю ссылки на них с сервера на фронт и все работает хорошо, но если вытащить ссылку при помощи средств разработчика то ее можно открыть в браузере(просто введя в адресную строку). Мне нужно запретить использовать эти ссылки везде кроме моего фронта. При помощи CORS эти ссылки нельзя встроить в другие сайты, а через браузер посмотреть можно. Решения которые я находил сводились к тому что не нужно хранить изображения в статических файлах и передавать ссылки на них, вместо этого предлагалось читать файлы через FileStream и отправлять File в методах контроллера. Мне эта идея не нравиться т.к. мне необходимо при загрузке страницы выводить на экран сотни файлов(примерно как в google картинках). Пример поведения которое я хочу иметь: ссылки на изображения в TelegrammWeb или ArtStation. Есть какие-нибудь ссылочки полезные для прочтения? Или хотя бы в каком направлении думать?

Comment: Один из возможных вариантов: [Авторизация статических файлов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#static-file-authorization)

Comment: В тему: [CSRF](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0), можно валидировать Referrer и класть в куки токен доступа.